# Create a Progress Bar with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm setting up a progress bar for a 9 page-form using react-router. My goal is the bar to update 1/9 of width for each page the user goes through - using Switch and Route components.

I'm currently having issues with accessing the number of children for Switch and automating the progress bar. Of course, a workaround could be a hardcoded 1/9th every time a component mounts, but that's not ideal.

```
// Routes I'm want to get 'progress' from
let routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/form/" exact component={Question0} />
        <Route path="/form/1" component={Question1} />
        <Route path="/form/2" component={Question2} />
        <Route path="/form/tip1" component={Tip1} />
        <Route path="/form/3" component={Question3} />
        <Route path="/form/tip2" component={Tip2} />
        <Route path="/form/4" component={Question4} />
        <Route path="/form/tip3" component={Tip3} />
        <Route path="/form/5" component={Question5} />
      </Switch>
    );
```

I also tried to play around with React.Children but was unsuccessful. 
Is there a more elegant solution for this? Thanks! :)

Comment: Before you move any further, let's say you had it working the way you want it, what happens if the user jumps directly to let's say /form/2? Looks like the progress should be tracked by a totally separate, stateful component that keeps track of whether each question has been answered or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom switch and use it instead of the default one:

```
const SwitchProgress = withRouter(props => {
  const progress = props.children.findIndex(
    route => matchPath(props.location.pathname, route.props)
  ) + 1;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Progress: {progress} / {props.children.length}</div>
      <Switch>
        {props.children}
      </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
});
```